linux command to coalesce repeated entries in output
I want to transform this:
dir1 file01
dir1 file02
dir1 file03
dir2 file04
dir2 file05
dir3 file06
dir4 file07
dir4 file08
dir4 file09
dir4 file10

Into the following:
dir1 file01 file02 file03
dir2 file04 file05
dir3 file06
dir4 file07 file08 file09 file10

I do this sort of thing often enough that I would be surprised if there's not already a command in linux that does this - I just don't know what it is or how to search for this.  What would you call this?  I would call it coalesce, but maybe that's just me.
Anyway, I can assume that the first column is already sorted, but if it were not - it would be OK if coalesce was dumb about processing the input.
I.E.
$ cat <<EOF | coalesce
a 1
a 2
b 3
a 4
EOF

a 1 2
b 3
a 4

Ideally, this command would also optionally indent the coalesced values on a separate line.
cat <<EOF | coalesce --level-indent 2
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 4
b 5
b 6
EOF

a
  1 2 3
b
  4 5 6

I suppose it would also be neat if it supported multiple levels of keys, too.
cat <<EOF | coalesce --level-indent 2
a b 1
a b 2
a b 3
a c 4
a c 5
d b 6
d b 7
d b 8
d c 1
EOF

a
  b
    1 2 3
  c
    4 5
d
  b
    6 7 8
  c
    1

I'm thinking that each line of tokens could be treated as a combination of "levels" to coalesce (at the front of the line) and "tokens" to group together.
Finally, it would be useful if the line of tokens could be considered "all levels", or "non-grouping".  When combined with a maximum number of levels to coalesce, it would produce something like the following.
cat <<EOF | coalesce --level-indent 2 --non-grouping --levels 3
2024-05-25 01:23:45 INFO: Something happened
2024-05-25 01:23:46 INFO: Something happened
2024-05-25 01:23:46 WARN: Something strange happened
2024-05-25 01:23:46 DEBUG: Something typical happened
EOF

2024-05-25
  01:23:45
    INFO: Something happened
  01:23:46
    INFO: Something happened
    WARN: Something strange happened
    DEBUG: Something typical happened

I could probably write something using awk that retains the seen levels from previous lines and collects matching tokens to be emitted once the level changes - but I'm hoping there's already a command that does this that I just don't know about.

Regarding "this command would also..." and "Finally, it would be useful if..." - please just ask 1 question per question to make each question standalone and easy for someone with a similar question to find an answer to that question in future. If you have additional questions after getting an answer to your first question then ask them in separate followup questions.

Fair enough - but I'm looking for the tool I wish existed, so I wanted to describe what I'm looking for beyond the trivial first example.

You're far more likely to get a solution to your problem if you get rid of the first 2 questions in your question and only show your final sample input and expected output from your question and your attempt to solve THAT problem yourself. You can safely assume there is no existing tool to do that specific thing but it'll be easy to do with an awk script. Make sure your example contains truly representative data, e.g. if your real input can contain spaces then don't post an example without them so you get a solution that'll work for your real data.

Tangentially, you want to avoid the useless cat

AFIK, there is no command around which would do this right out of the box. So I suggest that you write it yourself, using your language of choice.


I'm hoping there's already a command that does this that I just don't know about.

I can't think of any tool that does what you're looking for; at the very least there's no standard one that does it.

I could probably write something using awk that retains the seen levels from previous lines and collects matching tokens to be emitted once the level changes

Here you go:
awk -v indent='* ' -v max_levels=3 '
    {
        pad = ""
        for (i = 1; i < max_levels; i++)
            if ($i == a[i])
                pad = pad indent
            else
                for (i = i; i < max_levels; i++) {
                    print pad $i
                    pad = pad indent
                    a[i] = $i
                }
        printf("%s", pad)
        sub("^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*){"(max_levels-1)"}","")
        print
    }
'

2024-05-25
* 01:23:45
* * INFO: Something happened
* 01:23:46
* * INFO: Something happened
* * WARN: Something strange happened
* * DEBUG: Something typical happened


In TXR Lisp:
$ txr shoreup.tl < data
dir1 file01 file02 file03
dir2 file04 file05
dir3 file06
dir4 file07 file08 file09 file10

Code in shoreup.tl:
(flow (get-lines)
  (mapcar (op spl " "))
  (partition-by first)
  (mapdo (lambda (part)
           (let ((dir (first (first part)))
                 (files [mappend rest part]))
             (put-line `@dir @{files " "}`)))))

In TXR Pattern Language:
$ txr shoreup.txr data
dir1 file01 file02 file03
dir2 file04 file05
dir3 file06
dir4 file07 file08 file09 file10

Code in shoreup.txr:
@(repeat)
@dir @file0
@  (collect :gap 0 :vars (filen))
@dir @filen
@  (end)
@  (do (put-line `@dir @{(cons file0 filen) " "}`))
@(end)


in bash we do not have internal libraries, instead we have a lot of powerfull console tools to do anything you want. Try to use popular text-processing tools. Here is example in awk:
cat myfile.txt|awk 'BEGIN{n=""}{if (dir!=$1) {printf n$1" "$2 , n="\n"} else printf " "$2;dir=$1}END{printf n}'


This adds a newline to the beginning of the output, and more crucially, fails to print a final newline, which makes the output violate the POSIX definition of a text file. It's not hard to fix, per se. (Not my downvote, anyway.)

Updated command to remove new line in the beginning and add newline at the end.
